# How to intercept a web request

Tags: safari-extension

Is there something like Chromium's `chrome.webRequest` for Safari extensions?  I went through their documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SafariExtensionsReference/_index.html). The closest thing I could find was [`SafariBeforeNavigateEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Extensions/Reference/SafariBeforeNavigateEventClassRef/SafariBeforeNavigateEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010860). This will prevent the new page load but still would send the request to the server. Moreover I don't think it will call the listeners on AJAX requests. Anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We solved this problem by using "xmlhttprequest" overriding.

This is our content.js . We injected content.js as start script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     var myScriptTag = document.createElement('script');
     myScriptTag.src = safari.extension.baseURI + 'js/injectedToPage.js';
     document.body.appendChild(myScriptTag);     

    });
```

injected code is: (injectedToPage.js)

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.reallySend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (body) { 

        console.log("--req.body:---");
        console.log(body);

    this.reallySend(body);

};
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "any.html", true);
req.send(null);
```