# chrome.webRequest and safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari, firefox-addon-webextensions, safari-extension

I'm trying to port a Chrome/Firefox extension for Safari. But the extension use a lot a feature of those browsers that doesn't seem to exist in Safari : `chrome.webRequest` (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

The `chrome.webRequest` let you get information about every http requests sent (event from others tabs.).

I know that Safari has a very basic `safari.application.addEventListener` for `navigate` and `beforeNavigate`but Chrome give a lot more information (like `responseHeaders`) and other events (like `onBeforeRedirect` or `onErrorOccurred`).

Is there a way to achieve that with pure js or with the safari js-extension API ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept a web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937287/how-to-intercept-a-web-request)