# How to redirect a request in a Safari Content Blocker extension

Tags: safari, safari-extension, safari-app-extension

I am building a safari app extension that will redirect certain requests through a local proxy.

For example `https://tracking-script.com/track/user/123` needs to be redirected `http://localhost:9000`

The only problem that I do not know what domains are bad during application bootstrap. My bundle includes:
 1. MacOS app to host safari extension and content blocker 
 2. Safari extension where I can performance certain actions 
 3. Content Blocker which basically gives rules to Safari during application bootstrap
https://www.infoq.com/articles/safari-content-blockers/

Is it possible to dynamically inspect a request and redirect it through a given port?

I have a device on my local network that gives me these rules. So if a page requests `https://tracking-script.com/track/user/123` I first want to consult with my device running on localhost. If the response from the device says `this domain is bad` I want my content blocker to redirect this request to `http://localhost:9000` instead of going to the original URL.

Is this even possible in Safari/MacOS? I can do this in chrome and firefox extensions by hooking up on the onBeforeRequest hook. I make a request to my device and if the device says the domain is bad then I returned `{redirect_url: 'http://localhost:9000'}` and the browser redirects this request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try intercepting the HTTP request in the content script and then redirect the request to localhost if request. More details are given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937287/how-to-intercept-a-web-request).